# Grid: even border everywhere?

Tags: css

How to get even border around and between every item in grid? I've made a grid layout example, take a peek below. **PS!** It's responsive, play around with different screen widths.

**Problem 1:**
I cannot add `border: 2px solid #fff;` to every item, otherwise it will double the border between the items. I need even border between items and around whole thing.

**Problem 2:** border adds `width` which messes up the whole thing. Do I really have to use *2x more DOM elements* (add child `divs`) or is there a better way?

---

[CODEPEN LINK](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QNNEwZ)

---

```css
html {
  background: #000;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 900px;
}
.item {
  width: 50%;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
  float: left;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  .item {
     width: 33.3%;
     padding-bottom: 33.3%;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
  .item {
     width: 25%;
     padding-bottom: 25%;
  }
}


.one {
  background: #E65B60;
}
.two {
  background: #8873E3;
}
.three {
  background: #5BE67B;
}
.four {
  background: #E4E65B;
}
.five {
  background: #E6975B;
}
.six {
  background: #5BE6BD;
}
.seven {
  background: #C862E1;
}
.eight {
  background: #444;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item one"></div>
  <div class="item two"></div>
  <div class="item three"></div>
  <div class="item four"></div>
  <div class="item five"></div>
  <div class="item six"></div>
  <div class="item seven"></div>
  <div class="item eight"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: does it have to be 900px tall or can the wrapper conform to the height of the content?

Comment: @JosephMarikle It doesn't have to be 900px. Wrapper is _originally_ the height of the whole grid, feel free to change that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set `box-sizing: border-box;` so the wrapper and items include the border width in their calculation of width.  Then you could add a bottom and right border to the items and a top and left border to the wrapper.

```css
html {
  background: #000;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  /* height: 900px; */
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 0 solid white;
  border-width: 1px 0 0 1px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.item {
  width: 50%;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
  float: left;
  border: inherit;
  border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  .item {
     width: 33.333%;
     padding-bottom: 33.333%;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
  .item {
     width: 25%;
     padding-bottom: 25%;
  }
}


.one {
  background: #E65B60;
}
.two {
  background: #8873E3;
}
.three {
  background: #5BE67B;
}
.four {
  background: #E4E65B;
}
.five {
  background: #E6975B;
}
.six {
  background: #5BE6BD;
}
.seven {
  background: #C862E1;
}
.eight {
  background: #444;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item one"></div>
  <div class="item two"></div>
  <div class="item three"></div>
  <div class="item four"></div>
  <div class="item five"></div>
  <div class="item six"></div>
  <div class="item seven"></div>
  <div class="item eight"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

> `box-sizing:border-box;` to start with
>
> `padding` on 2 sides of container
>
> `border` on the 2 other sides of elements
>
> finalyse with `background-clip: content-box` to see through borders and contain background-color inside the boxes.
>
> eventually, `display:flex;` can be used so it gives a Block Formating Context To childs
>
> Childs with BFC can be grown with a floatting pseudo to easily insert content aside, `padding` is then instead,  used on pseudo with a single value for a square : `100%`

```css
html {
  background: #000;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 2px 0 0 2px ;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.item {
  min-width: 25%;
  /* flex item handle floatting elements */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-right: 2px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
  background-clip: content-box!important;/* !important because i do not want to write again in every class below */
}
.item:before {
  content: '';
  float: left;
  padding-top: 100%;
  /* will make boxe be at min-height a square */
}
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  .item {
    width: 33.3%;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
  .item {
    width: 25%;
  }
}
.one {
  background: #E65B60;
}
.two {
  background: #8873E3;
}
.three {
  background: #5BE67B;
}
.four {
  background: #E4E65B;
}
.five {
  background: #E6975B;
}
.six {
  background: #5BE6BD;
}
.seven {
  background: #C862E1;
}
.eight {
  background: #444;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item one"></div>
  <div class="item two"></div>
  <div class="item three"></div>
  <div class="item four"></div>
  <div class="item five"></div>
  <div class="item six"></div>
  <div class="item seven"></div>
  <div class="item eight"></div>
</div>
```

your codepen forked : http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/JXXKME